# body height 100% not being computed

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` I want to extend to the bottom of the page. The standard approach for this seems to be to set the `min-height` to `100%` for the `div` you want, the `body`, and the `html`. I have done this, however, browsers (tested on both firefox and mobile safari) don't seem to care. Simplified code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
         html{
              min-height: 100%;
              position: relative;
         }
         body {
             min-height: 100%;
             position: relative;
         }
         #main {
             min-height: 100%;
             overflow:hidden;
         }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='main'>
             <p>content</p>
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

A closer inspection with firebug reveals that it reads the css is read, and says that it computed a height of 986px for html and body elements (on a 1080p monitor), but only 517px for the div. What's really weird though is that the layout tab seems to indicate the height of the body element is only 517px, even though it computed it should be 986px.

So the browser knows what the height should be, but refuses to actually set it. What the actual ...

EDIT: I came across a similar question, which was answered with the suggestion one uses `vh` instead of percentages. This worked for the `body` and `html` tags, but when used on the `div` it makes it longer than the page because there's actually a header above the div. So I'd use percentages, but they result in the same issue I had with `body` originally: it's read, computed, but not executed.

Comment: An ad-hoc crud approach I am using right now at one project is `html { height: 100%; } body { margin: 0; min-height: 100%; display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; } #main { flex: 1; }`, then #main should be stretched perfectly in all modern browsers IIRC.

Comment: All is standard documented behavior of flex, not relying on browser quirks. Setting height on html/body elements feels more fragile to me and subject to browser implementation though.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the first comment did the trick. I have no idea how, but it works now. Leaving the code here for future reference:

```
html { 
    height: 100%; 
} 
body { 
    margin: 0; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    display: flex; 
    flex-flow: 
    column nowrap; 
} 
#main { 
    flex: 1; 
}
```

Thanks, Anton Strogonoff!

Comment: It works mainly because your `html` has been set to 100%

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code may be it's help you.

```
<div id=fullheight>
Lorem Ipsum  
</div>

 * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body, #fullheight {
min-height: 100% !important;
height: 100%;
}

#fullheight {
width: 250px;
background: blue;
}
```